# In NestJS 10 with TypeORM, how do I update a field in my entity's @OneToOne member?

Tags: service, nestjs, typeorm, updates, one-to-one

I'm using NestJS 10 with TypeORM 0.3.17.  I have defined this entity wiht a @OneToOne relationship

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

    ...
  @Column()
  password: string;

  @OneToOne(() => Contact, {
    cascade: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    nullable: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'contact_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  contact?: Contact;

}
```

I have defined a corresponding UpdateUserDto and CreateUserDto ...

```
export class UpdateUserDto extends PartialType(CreateUserDto) {
}

export class CreateUserDto {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  refreshToken: string;
  contact: CreateContactDto;
}
```

How do I create a service method to update a single field from my Contact object?  I tried this

```
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    private readonly userRepository: UserRepository, // import as usual
  ) {}
    ...
  async update(
    id: string,
    updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto,
  ): Promise<UpdateResult> {
    return this.userRepository.update(id, updateUserDto);
  }
```

but when I call this method with the parameters

```
this.usersService.update(userId, {
  contact: {
    firstName: 'Dave',
    lastName: 'Test',
    mailingAddress: {
      addressLine1: '321 oklahoma',
      city: 'Springfield',
      zipCode: '90210',
      region: { id: '123' }
    }
  }
});
```

It fails with the runtime error

```
[ExceptionsHandler] Property "contact.firstName" was not found in "User". Make sure your query is correct.
```

**Edit:** Adding contact entity ...

```
import { Address } from 'src/addresses/entities/address.entity';
import { User } from 'src/users/entities/user.entity';
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Contact {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

...

  @OneToOne((type) => Address, {
    cascade: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'mailing_address_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  mailingAddress: Address;

}
```

Comment: Could you add the Contact entity definition?

Comment: @OMartinez-NeT, it is added

Answer (score 0):

First of all, find the user by ID:

```
const user = this.userRepository.findOneBy({ id });
if (!user) throw new NotFoundException();
```

Then create Contact Object;

```
    const contact = new Contact();
    contact.firstName = "Dave";
    ...
```

And finally, you can save the relation :

```
    user.contact = contact;
    userRepository.save(user);
```

Comment: Here you are doing two SQL operations -- one to retrieve the user and another to udpate it.  I would like to do a single operation.  Why isn't the code I have to do that working?

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I will do this:

```js
const user = await User.findOneOrFail({
  where: { id || IsNull() }, //in case of id null and not getting the first row in db
  relations: ['contact'],
});
Object.assign(user.contact, {
  firstName: 'Dave',
  lastName: 'test',
  //...your rest
}); //if the user doesn't have a contact, it will create a new one
await user.save();
```

if you want to update multiple relations nested user Entity

```js
Object.assign(user, {
        contact: {
          ...user.contact,
          firstName: firstName,
          lastname: lastName,
          //...your rest
        },
        //...your object
      });
```

remember to add relations and your relation must have cascade

Comment: WHy doesn't the "update" call I'm executing work?  What I'm trying to avoid is two SQL operations (one to lookup and a second to update).

Comment: TypeORM QueryBuilder expects the properties you're updating to be direct properties of the entity being queried. This is because TypeORM uses the entity's metadata to generate the SQL query, and it does not know anything about nested properties or relationships.

Comment: Is the implication of this that I have to write multiple update methods -- one for the direct properties of the User and other methods for updating the User relations?

Comment: or you can do like me, find first, update both

Comment: Yes but is my question about the implication correct?  Your answer is updating only a single relation.  If I wanted to update 3 relations from my user, per your logic, I would have to write "Object.assign" three times, is that right?

Comment: yeah I updated my answer to response your question, check it out

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that you declared `@JoinColumn` in both sides in `Contact` and `User`. Read [one-to-one-relations](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/one-to-one-relations):

> @JoinColumn which is required and must be set only on one side of the relation

From your model It seems `@JoinColumn` has to be in the `Contact` entity instead of user. Also you should check if `owner_id` is the correct FK that connects to `User`. Remember with this definition:

```js
  @OneToOne(() => User, { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'owner_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  owner?: User;
```

You're saying "Get the user related to this contact where my FK is `owner_id` (meaning **owner_id** has to exist in contact) and the column in `User` is `id`.

Comment: IN light of what you said, I removed the "User" association from teh Contact entity (so only the User entity has a relation to Contact) but I still get the same error when attempting to update a user entity with a Contact object.

Comment: Hey @Dave I overlooked the issue, but it seems that this is a typeorm limitation https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4477, in this comment though https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4477#issuecomment-719575191 you can check how they work this around to make the update in one single operation!

Comment: I'm not understanding.  I thought you said don't put @JoinColumn on both the parent and child.  Because links break over time, could you put what I need to into an SO answer?